# Cancel \rowcolors for a specific cell

Tags: tables, color, colortbl, rowcolor

In some tables, the cell in the top-left corner is meant to be left empty. To do this in tables that use `\rowcolors`, I do `\cellcolor{white}`. However, I'm now using some old tables of this kind in a Beamer slideshow that has a background, so I'd like to be able to simply cancel the row colour for a specific cell (*i.e.*, make a transparent cell that lets the background appear) rather than to fill it with white (which actually looks less pretty than simply leaving the cell as it is in such circumstances).

In the following code, I use a dumb `\colorbox` to fake the presence of a background for the third instance of the dummy table. Note that my real background is a gradient, so filling the cell with “the colour used in the background” is not a solution.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\emptycell}{}

\begin{tabular}{c c c}
    \emptycell & A & B \\
    Plop       & 1 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}

\rowcolors{1}{blue!15}{blue!10}
\renewcommand{\emptycell}{\cellcolor{white}}

\begin{tabular}{c c c}
    \emptycell & A & B \\
    Plop       & 1 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}

\colorbox{red!10}{%
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
        \emptycell & A & B \\
        Plop       & 1 & 2 \\
    \end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried some pretty crazy stuff with no success. I went as far as this (go ahead, laugh at me):

```
\newcommand{\emptycell}{%
    \multicolumn{1}{
        >{%
            \let\rowc@lors\relax%
            \def\@evenrowcolor{\@norowcolor}%
            \def\@oddrowcolor{\@norowcolor}%
            \let\rownum\relax%
        } c
    }{}%
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this here:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}


\rowcolors{1}{blue!15}{blue!10}

\makeatletter
\global\let\oriCT@@do@color\CT@@do@color 

\colorbox{red!10}{%
\begin{tabular}{c c c}         
 \global\let\CT@@do@color\relax           %deactivate
&
 \global\let\CT@@do@color\oriCT@@do@color %reactivate
A 
&
B \\
  Plop       & 1 & 2 \\
    \end{tabular}%
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Haha, I was kind of expecting some esoteric `\relax`-based things like this. Thanks. I had to fiddle a little bit in my true table because of `siunitx` columns, but everything was fine in the end. Too bad the reactivation has to be done manually (had to make a `\restorecell` command in addition to the `\emptycell` one), but that's a minor issue, I guess.

Answer (score 2):

With its key `corners`, the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` detects the empty corners and the cells in that corners won't be colored by the command `\rowcolors` (built-in in `{NiceTabular}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{red!10}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c}[color-inside,corners=NW] % NW : north-west
   \rowcolors{blue!15}{blue!10}
               & A & B \\
    Plop       & 1 & 2 \\
\end{NiceTabular}%

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

For information: if you add rules with the key `hvlines`, the rules won't be drawn in the empty corners.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{red!10}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c}[hvlines,color-inside,corners=NW] % NW : north-west
   \rowcolors{blue!15}{blue!10}
               & A & B \\
    Plop       & 1 & 2 \\
\end{NiceTabular}%

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

---

`nicematrix` provides also a special color `nocolor`. When that color is used in a cell with `\cellcolor{nocolor}`, no color will be added to that cell, even if a command `\rowcolor` is in force in that row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\pagecolor{red!10}

\begin{NiceTabular}{c c c c c c c c }[color-inside]
   \rowcolors{blue!15}{blue!10}
   A & B & C & \cellcolor{nocolor} D & E & F & G & H \\
   A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H \\
\end{NiceTabular}%

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the third code]